# Difference Between var.method() and $(var).method() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the difference between the following two

```
var link = $("a#home");

// These two:
link.text("Go Home");    // 1.
$(link).text("Go Home"); // 2.
```

Comment: 2 has an extraneous function call

Comment: link is an jQuery object. The first call will call the 'text' function directly. The second call will first pass the link object to jQuery that returns a jQuery object and then call the 'text' function.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker can you elaborate?

Comment: @Hoyen so I assume the first one is faster?

Comment: @collinhaines: `link` is already a jQuery object, passing `link` to jQuery again `$(link)` isn't necessary

Comment: @collinhaines yes it is faster

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are already creating a jQuery object that is being assigned to your variable, there is no need to wrap it in `$()` again.

One common convention is to use a `$` prefix for variables that are already jQuery objects so it makes your code more readable with regard to what is already stored as jQuery

Example:

```
var $link = $("a#home");
// we know that $link is jQuery object assuming prefix is only used for jQuery objects
```

Your example #2 is equivalent to writing:

```
$( $("a#home") ).text("Go Home");
```

It is clearly redundant when looking at it in this form to wrap the object in `$()` again

Answer (score 3):

Both perform the same task, but as mentioned in a comment, the latter is wrapping (an already-wrapped) jQuery reference. jQuery is smart enough, however, to know this and proceed as normal.

From my own experience, I tend to have jQuery variables retain the `$` prefix. Then, as I bounce between other variables, it's clear to me what is and isn't already wrapped. e.g.

```
var $link = $('#home');
$link.text("Go Home");
```

Also, for what it's worth, if you're referencing an element by it's ID (`#home`) there is no need to reference the tag.